# Linker Command Failed with exit code 1 (Use -v to see invocation) iOS Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

In my application I'm using a static library named `ABC.a` in that library in a c file named `Layout.c` there is a function called `init()`. And I linked the library to the projects and added the `.h` file. The program is compiled without error but while linking the function its throwing the error. Why?

Info: I've added that static library in build phases also.

And the library is built for armv7, armv7s and arm64. bitcode enabled: No and Build active architectures : NO

Example error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "AMID_INIT(int*, int*, int)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController microphone:hasAudioReceived:withBufferSize:withNumberOfChannels:] in Test_lto.o
  "amid_Val(float const*, int, int*, int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController microphone:hasAudioReceived:withBufferSize:withNumberOfChannels:] in Test_lto.o
```

Please help two days gone for this.

Comment: At a guess, the headers for the library don't have C++ guards and you're using them in an objective-C++ program. try wrapping the `#import 'lib.h'` in an `extern "C" {\n#import 'lib.h'\n}` to see if that helps things.

Comment: try this : If your Architectures and Valid Architectures are all right, you may check whether you have add $(inherited) to Other Linker Flags.

Comment: @Petesh Your comment is absolutely correct. Awesome man. You saved a lot of my time. Thanks. Put an answer I will check it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on the fact that you mention that the `.a` file is generated from a `c` file. The linker error:

```
  "AMID_INIT(int*, int*, int)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController microphone:hasAudioReceived:withBufferSize:withNumberOfChannels:] in Test_lto.o
```

indicates that the `AMID_INIT` definition came from a C++/Objective-C++ file - this is because `C` files would not have information about the parameters of the routine.

From this I was able to surmise that the library header file did not have c++ guards.

Three approaches in this case - wrap all imports of the library header file in the C++ code with something like:

```
extern "C" {
#import "lib.h"
}
```

or create a `lib.hpp` file, containing:

```
#pragma once
extern "C" {
#import "lib.h"
}
```

and `#import 'lib.hpp'` instead, or fix the `lib.h` file by adding the standard name mangling preventative:

… near start of lib.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

… near end of lib.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This allows you to keep using the `lib.h` with both `C` and `C++` compilers by declaring that all the routines offered by `lib.h` are exposed using `C` linkage, rather than `C++` linkage.